# UITableView Section header color misbehaving

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I changed the color of my custom `UITableViewCell` section header and while I'm scrolling inside my `tableView` it changes its alpha, I guess. Some are kind of transparent and the others have a solid color.

What is wrong?

```
// Customize HeaderView of Sections
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    // This changes the header background
    view.tintColor = UIColor(hue: 0.13, saturation: 0.13, brightness: 0.13, alpha: 1)

    // Gets the header view as a UITableViewHeaderFooterView and changes the text colour
    var headerView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    headerView.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest to configure your header view in this method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

I would use the `willDisplayHeader...` for other purposes than primarily configuring the appearance.